# hover layer hides graph in plotly.js

Tags: plotly

I'm showing a table with small plotly.js graphs.

The graphs show a trend (simple line plot), and I would like to show the x-y value when the user hovers over points.

The problem is that the graph is small, so the hover shape hides it:
[image]

This is confusing since the user can't know which point he is hover over.

Is there a way to "move" the hover layer away from the graph?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a custom hover div and showing it on hover.